# Life of independent parts placed in Parallel given pdf of individual parts.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

> I have attempted the question below but am getting conflicting methods
>   from different people and now I am really confused. In particular
>   tutors are multiplying by 4 instead of raising to the fourth power in
>   this part:   P( Lifetime of all individual parts $\le$ $y$) = $ [y^3/(400)^3 ]^4 = y^{12}/(400)^{12} $. This tells me that I should
>   take the Union of the independent probabilities instead of their
>   Intersection. But this does not make sense to me since its a parallel system. Maybe I am completely missing the mark here. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction thanks!

*Let X denote the life (in weeks) of a certain part. Suppose that the PDF of X is

$f(x)=3x^2/(400)^3$, $0<x< 400$: 
To decrease the probability of failing, four independent parts are placed in parallel
so that all must fail if the system is to fail. Let Y be the life (in weeks) of this
parallel system.
i. Find the CDF  of Y .*

**My answer so far:**

Probability of each individual part failing before week $x$ is $F_X(x) = $$\int_0^{x} 3x^2/(400)^3   dx = x^3/(400)^3 $

Similarly, Probability one part fails before week $y$ , $= y^3/(400)^3 $

CDF of $Y$ = $F_Y(y)$ = P( Y $\le$ $y$)

P( Y $\le$ $y$) = P( Lifetime of whole system $\le$ $y$)

P( Lifetime of whole system $\le$ $y$) = P( Lifetime of all individual parts $\le$ $y$)

P( Lifetime of all individual parts $\le$ $y$) = P( Lifetime of first part $\le$ $y$) AND P( Lifetime of second part $\le$ $y$) AND P( Lifetime of third part $\le$ $y$) AND P( Lifetime of fourth part $\le$ $y$)

Then:

P( Lifetime of all individual parts $\le$ $y$) = $ [y^3/(400)^3 ]^4 = y^{12}/(400)^{12} $

Hence:

$F_Y(y)$= $y^{12}/(400)^{12}  ,for $ $0<y< 400$:

Answer (score 0):

In general, for random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$:
$$\left\{\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i\leqslant t \right\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i\leqslant t\}.$$
If the $X_i$ are i.i.d. with cdf $F$ then it follows that 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left(\left\{\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}X_i\leqslant t \right\}\right) &=
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i\leqslant t\}\right)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(X_i\leqslant t)\\
&=\mathbb P(X_i\leqslant t)^n\\
&=F(t)^n.
\end{align} In this case, $F(t) = \frac1{400^3}t^3\mathsf 1_{(0,400)}(t)+\mathsf 1_{[400,\infty)}$ and $n=4$, so the cdf of $\max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant 4}X_i$ is $$F(t)^4 = \frac1{400^{12}}t^{12}\mathsf 1_{(0,400)}(t)+\mathsf 1_{[400,\infty)}. $$